# No direct hints about methods or attributes

Tags: c++, eclipse, adt

I've got two annoying problems:

1) I can't see any methods in hints, for example after writing std:: I should be able to see std namespace methods and so on, but there is no action

2) I can't use object's method in such situations:

```
vector<string> somevector;
somevector[0].size(); //compilation error

string& str = somevector[0];
str.size(); //now it's working fine..
```

I'm 100% sure I changed something in ADT's settings, but I have no idea what it was ..

Comment: when you want some hint from eclipse, hit `CTRL + SPACE`

Comment: So, what compilation error did you get? Did you include `<vector>`? Are you `using std::vector` and `using std::string`?

Comment: vector was just an example, it happens with every class, not only from std

Comment: @billz I can see 'No Default Proposals' message on any object I use this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [codeblocks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks.berlios/files/codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe/download) for c++. It helps you to write a more readable code. Use ctrl + space in order to activate codeblocks hints. When you call somevector[0].size(); your compiler "thinks" that you have a vector of this kind `vector<string> somevector[someSize];`  but obviously you don't. That's why you are getting an error.